# How to access a running Word Document using OleObject?

Tags: javascript, ms-office

I use Javascript Code below to try to access a Word Document which has been opened on my system.
I would like to get it full path of the document.

```
var wordApp = Sys.OleObject("Word.Application");
var path = wordApp.ActiveDocument.FullName;
```

But actually the path is return as null, when I debug into the program, I found `Sys.OleObject` will create a new word process, so there are two Word processes in my system,
I doubt that's the reason why path is null.

Comment: Are you trying to open a new instance or do you wish to open a saved document?

Comment: @Nadeem_MK Humm, I think neither of them. I don't want to open a new instance, because I have a word is open. I don't want to open a saved document, because the word is not saved, but it's open and I don't know the name / path of the word. Why I want to use oleobject, because there is a word opened currently, I want to get it name and path (temporary path in system).